# Problem with Function in HTML - If-Else Clauses - Mailing

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, mailing

I have the following code, but it has a small issue. What it does is send me an email with the feedback from the rating. This email is sent correctly when the rating is 4 or 5 stars.

```
javascript
Copiar
if (rating >= 1 && rating <= 3) {
    subject = `Alert - You Have a Low Product Rating 200000${vtValue}`;
    body = `You have a new product rating\n\nRating: ${rating}\nProduct: ${mluValue}\nComments: ${feedback}\nSale: 200000${vtValue}`;
} else if (rating >= 4 && rating <= 5) {
    subject = `You Have a Good Product Rating 200000${vtValue}`;
    body = `You have a new product rating\n\nRating: ${rating}\nProduct: ${mluValue}\nSale: 200000${vtValue}`;
}
```

However, when the rating is between 1 and 3 stars, I encounter an issue where it doesn't work as it should and I receive an empty email. It doesn't use the correct subject or body.

_subject

body

Submitted 05:14 PM - 06 March 2024

I have tried different solutions, but I can't make it work when the rating is between 1 and 3 stars.

Here it's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Universal Importaciones</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"> <!-- Agregar Font Awesome para íconos de estrella -->
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #006bd6; /* Fondo azul */
        color: #FFFFFF; /* Texto blanco */
    }
    h1, h2, h3 {
        margin: 10px;
    }
    #votacion {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    .stars {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: row-reverse; /* Cambiar la dirección de las estrellas */
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .stars input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
    }
    .stars label {
        font-size: 5em;
        color: #ddd;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: color 0.3s;
    }
    .stars label:hover,
    .stars input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label,
    .stars input[type="radio"]:hover ~ label {
        color: #ffd700; /* Color de estrella seleccionada */
    }
    #feedback-box {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #feedback-box textarea {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 5px; /* Redondear bordes de la textarea */
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #feedback-box button {
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: #ff03a7; /* Color del botón */
        color: #FFFFFF; /* Texto blanco */
        font-size: 14px; /* Tamaño del texto */
        border: none;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px; /* Redondear bordes del botón */
    }
    #mensaje-final {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    #footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #footer p {
        margin: 5px;
    }
    #footer a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    #footer a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #footer .icons {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .stars label {
            font-size: 3.5em;
        }
        #feedback-box textarea {
            width: 90%;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="https://www.universalimportaciones.uy/assets/uni-logo-vert-trim-0f197ea90854816ad0f09338fb14b035b3165db7eaf7f2c9b5e5802c4bbf1403.png" alt="Logo de Universal Importaciones" style="width: 200px; height: auto; margin-top: 20px;">

<div id="votacion">
    <h2>¿Cómo Calificarías tu Experiencia de Compra con Nosotros?</h2>
    <div class="stars">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="star5"><label for="star5"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id="star4"><label for="star4"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id="star3"><label for="star3"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id="star2"><label for="star2"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="star1"><label for="star1"></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="feedback-box" style="display: none;">
    <h3>¿Cuéntanos qué le faltó al producto para tener una Mejor Calificación?</h3>
    <textarea id="feedback" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <button onclick="enviarFeedback()">Enviar</button>
</div>

<div id="mensaje-final" style="display: none;">
    <p style="color: black;">Agradecemos tu respuesta, estamos en la búsqueda de mejorar tu experiencia de compra y tus comentarios son muy importantes para nosotros.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i> Tienes Alguna Duda o Consulta? Contáctanos</p>
    <div class="icons">
        <style>
    .whatsapp-link {
        color: lime;
    }
</style>

        <a href="https://wa.me/59892478000" class="whatsapp-link"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp" style="color: lime;"></i> WhatsApp</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/js/all.min.js"></script> <!-- Agregar script de Font Awesome -->
<script>
    const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.stars input[type="radio"]');
    const feedbackBox = document.getElementById('feedback-box');
    const mensajeFinal = document.getElementById('mensaje-final');

    stars.forEach(star => {
        star.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const ratingValue = this.value;
            const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const mluValue = params.get('mlu');
            const vtValue = params.get('vt');

            if (ratingValue <= 3) {
                feedbackBox.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                window.open(`https://reviews.mercadolibre.com.uy/review/MLU${mluValue}?origin=my-reviews-pending&rating=${ratingValue}`);
                enviarFeedback(ratingValue, mluValue, vtValue);
            }
        });

        star.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            const rating = parseInt(this.value);
            for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
                if (i < rating) {
                    stars[i].nextElementSibling.style.color = '#ffd700';
                } else {
                    stars[i].nextElementSibling.style.color = '#ddd';
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function enviarFeedback(rating, mluValue, vtValue) {
        const feedback = document.getElementById('feedback').value;
        let subject = '';
        let body = '';

        if (rating >= 1 && rating <= 3) {
            subject = `Alerta - Tienes una Baja Calificación de Producto 200000${vtValue}`;
            body = `Tienes una nueva calificación de Producto\n\nCalificación: ${rating}\nProducto: ${mluValue}\nComentarios: ${feedback}\nVenta: 200000${vtValue}`;
        } else if (rating >= 4 && rating <= 5) {
            subject = `Tienes una Buena Calificación de Producto 200000${vtValue}`;
            body = `Tienes una nueva calificación de Producto\n\nCalificación: ${rating}\nProducto: ${mluValue}\nVenta: 200000${vtValue}`;
        }

        const form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('action', 'https://formspree.io/mdoqdkbl');
        form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');

        const emailInput = document.createElement('input');
        emailInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        emailInput.setAttribute('name', 'Email');
        emailInput.setAttribute('value', 'franco.vera@ortopediauniversal.com.uy');

        const subjectInput = document.createElement('input');
        subjectInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        subjectInput.setAttribute('name', '_subject');
        subjectInput.setAttribute('value', subject);

        const bodyInput = document.createElement('input');
        bodyInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        bodyInput.setAttribute('name', 'Body');
        bodyInput.setAttribute('value', body);

        form.appendChild(emailInput);
        form.appendChild(subjectInput);
        form.appendChild(bodyInput);

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();

        mensajeFinal.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if rating <=3 show the feedback box.. else enviarFeedback(ratingValue, mluValue, vtValue)` - then in the feedbackbox feedback button you only have `enviarFeedback()` - you don't pass the 3 parameters, so the rating in the sendFeedback is `undefined`

Comment: Get the ratingValue, mluValue, vtValue when inside `function enviarFeedback() {` instead of passing them.

Comment: You mean like this:
stars.forEach(star => {
        star.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (this.value <= 3) {
                feedbackBox.style.display = 'block';
                enviarFeedback(ratingValue, mluValue, vtValue);
            } else {

Comment: or using enviarFeedback(ratingValue, mluValue, vtValue); previous the if else

Comment: No: `function enviarFeedback() { const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); ...`

Comment: There are no functions in HTML. I think you mean functions in JavaScript.

Comment: @freedomn-m Can you tell me answer, I don't understand what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  freedomn-m
The sendFeedback was undefined

```
stars.forEach(star => {
    star.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const ratingValue = this.value;
        const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const mluValue = params.get('mlu');
        const vtValue = params.get('vt');

        if (this.value <= 3) {
            feedbackBox.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            window.open('https://g.page/r/CXlO12LsUkhoEB0/review');
        }
    });

    star.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        const rating = parseInt(this.value);
        for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
            if (i < rating) {
                stars[i].nextElementSibling.style.color = '#ffd700';
            } else {
                stars[i].nextElementSibling.style.color = '#ddd';
            }
        }
    });
});

function enviarFeedback() {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const mluValue = params.get('mlu');
    const vtValue = params.get('vt');
    const feedback = document.getElementById('feedback').value;
    const ratingValue = document.querySelector('.stars input[type="radio"]:checked').value;

    let subject = '';
    let body = '';
```